# MFC OnSize() issue with Invalidate

Tags: c++, windows, mfc, invalidation

I'm just starting to learn the basics of MFC so I've written a small practice program that just tracks coordinates relative to the window and the screen on each move and resize, everything works great except for this:

[image]

How can I get it so that there are no trailing paints left behind when I resize the window?

Here is my onSize() code:

```
void CMainFrame::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy)
{
CFrameWnd::OnSize(nType, cx, cy);

// TODO: Add your message handler code here

// Get the window
CDC* dc;
dc = GetDC();
CRect rect;
GetWindowRect(rect);
InvalidateRect(rect);

// This if statement just makes sure new red text coordinates are not printed immediately upon starting the program
if (numSizeCalls > 1){ 
    // Set up the font for future text output
    CFont myfont;
    VERIFY(myfont.CreateFont(
        20, // nHeight in points
        0,  // nWidth
        0,  // nEscapement
        0,  // nOrientation
        FW_NORMAL,  // nWeight
        TRUE,   // bItalic
        FALSE,  // bUnderline
        0,  // cStrikeOut
        ANSI_CHARSET,   // nCharSet
        OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS,        // nOutPrecision
        CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS,        // nClipPrecision
        DEFAULT_QUALITY,              // nQuality
        DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_SWISS,  // nPitchAndFamily
        _T("Arial")));  // lpszFacename 
    dc->SetTextColor(RGB(255, 0, 0));
    dc->SelectObject(myfont);
    DeleteObject(myfont);

    // Set window coordinates relative to client area
    ScreenToClient(&rect);

    // Format them for TextOut
    CString tl;
    tl.Format(L"%d %d ; ", rect.top, rect.left);
    CString tr;
    tr.Format(L"%d %d ; ", rect.top, rect.right);
    CString bl;
    bl.Format(L"%d %d ; ", rect.bottom, rect.left);
    CString br;
    br.Format(L"%d %d", rect.bottom, rect.right);

    // Get position for TextOut
    TextOutYPosition += 20;

    // Print them
    dc->TextOut(5, TextOutYPosition, tl + tr + bl + br, _tcslen(tl) + _tcslen(tr) + _tcslen(bl) + _tcslen(br));

    // Set coords relative to the screen
    GetWindowRect(&rect);

    // Format them for TextOut
    tl.Format(L"%d %d ; ", rect.top, rect.left);
    tr.Format(L"%d %d ; ", rect.top, rect.right);
    bl.Format(L"%d %d ; ", rect.bottom, rect.left);
    br.Format(L"%d %d", rect.bottom, rect.right);

    // Get position for TextOut
    TextOutYPosition += 20;

    // Print them
    dc->TextOut(5, TextOutYPosition, tl + tr + bl + br, _tcslen(tl) + _tcslen(tr) + _tcslen(bl) + _tcslen(br));
}
numSizeCalls++;
}
```

Comment: What does your OnSize code look like?

Comment: @MarkRansom I've updated my question with the code

Answer (score 0):

`InvalidateRect` takes a rectangle in *client* coordinates. You're passing it the results of `GetWindowRect`, which returns *screen* coordinates. The window isn't being invalidated properly, thus not being erased.

Note that when the window is erased, the painting you do in the OnSize function will be erased too. You should really reserve all your painting for the OnPaint function to prevent this problem.

Comment: I've made the change from GetWindowRect to GetClientRect before I InvalidateRect, and the trailing paint is still occuring :/

Comment: @Riptyde4 what does your OnEraseBkgnd look like?

Comment: first time I'm hearing about that message, what do I need to do inside the body of the handler?

Comment: @Riptyde4 if you don't have a handler then the default should be correct - it erases the background of the window by drawing a solid rectangle.